# How to overwrite repository version when using 'show diff' in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

In "Local Changes", after clicking "show diff", it shows the diffs side by side in two panels. However, it seems it only shows an option to 'accept' the repository version. I need to overwrite it using my own version. I can't find an option to do that. Where is the trick?

More specifically, in my pom.xml file, I want to replace this line:

```
<version>0.8.0</version>
```

with my local version:

```
<version>0.9.0</version>
```

Shouldn't I overwrite it first before I commit?

Comment: You probably need to commit your changes.

Comment: Shouldn't I commit first?

Comment: Commit is a proper action for updating files.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to overwrite it before you commit. When you commit your changes, they will will be applied to the repository version. The diff is merely to see how a file was changed, and revert if necessary